# Trying to find a question I remember seeing

Tags: support, search

The question was about a Gmail user that wanted to know which email messages were forwarded on their Gmail account. What happened was a friend (or someone the person knows) logged in a while ago and made all emails forward a copy to him. The owner of the account didn't realize this until much later and wanted to know which emails this friend has a copy of.

I've been trying many different queries, but can't find it. Here's the last query I used:

`site:webapps.stackexchange.com (gmail OR google) (friend OR someone I know) (~forward OR copy) (address OR account OR email)`

The reason I'm trying to find it is that the answers might help this [similar question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5229/how-to-determine-if-gmail-forwarding-rule-worked).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Is there any way to tell which of my messages have been auto-forwarded](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3273/is-there-any-way-to-tell-which-of-my-messages-have-been-auto-forwarded)

Here's the [search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=gmail+forward) I used.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I couldn't find it. I would have sworn it was deleted. Good find and thanks!